# Correct typographic notation for variables with subscripts and parts of matrices?

Tags: notation

I’m writing a scientific text and I’m trying to conform to the ISO 80000-2 standard regarding mathematical notation. After going through the standard there are still two situations I’m unsure about:

**Situation 1)**:

What is the proper typesetting format for variables denoted with subscripts? For example, given the following expression:

$x_{new} = x_{old} + 1$

Should the “new” and “old” text be italic/bold, uppercase/lowercase etc.? Are there any rules for this? ISO 80000-2 does not mention variable names including subscripts as far as I can tell.

**Situation 2)**:

If $\mathbf{X}$ is a matrix, denoted in uppercase, italic, bold. And I want to refer to the first column vector of the matrix, should that be:
$\mathbf{x}_1$? 
I.e., lowercase bold italic to indicate that this is a vector, not a matrix. Or should it be denoted as $\mathbf{X}_1$ to indicate that the quantity is taken from something which is a matrix? Or are both notations wrong?

Comment: $\boldsymbol{X}$ is denoted in uppercase, italic, bold.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just didn’t know how to typeset it that way in the question. What latex command did you use just now to write in bold and italic in math mode?

Comment: $\mathit{\mathbf{X}}$ perhaps using `\mathit{\mathbf{X}}` but that's more of a LaTex stackexchange question already asked.

Comment: It was \boldsymbol{X}.

Answer (score 3):

You are using

```
$x_{new}$
```

which is wrong anyways.  Typeset

```
$x_{\text{new}}$
```

to get $x_{\text{new}}$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So you are saying then that subscripts should be written in non-italic, non-bold, lowercase letters? Or is the choice of uppercase/uppercase up to personal taste? Also, are you basing this answer on a standard you can refer me to or is this just your opinion?

Comment: I don't know the standards, but I know if you don't surround them with the `\text{}` part you get then treated as variable names by default in effect with LaTeX and MathJaX.

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX